# AccessViolationException in StreamReader.ReadToEnd()

Tags: c#, wpf, webrequest, access-violation, streamreader

I'm sometimes getting a AccessViolationException when calling ReadToEnd() on a WebRequest response stream.

I create a background thread to do this operation, post the results back to the UI thread, and let the thread exit on its own. My app does this about once per minute. It seems to run fine for a few hours, and then randomly crash.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Thank you very much!

**Code**

```
String uri = ... ;
String data;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Timeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds;

using (Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    data = reader.ReadToEnd(); // <-- exception...sometimes...
```

**Exception**

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
at // my code here
```

Comment: I remember there have been some 'bugs' in the past. What version of .NET are you addressing? Also, did you turn of your virus scanner while testing?

Comment: The app is currently targeting .NET 3.5 (I'm running Win7), and I don't have antivirus on this machine. (I originally targeted .NET 4, and the issue occurred then as well).

Comment: Are you newing up a Thread class each time or using BackgroundWorker? How are you posting the message back to the UI...via Invoke or BeginInvoke? Are you sure your thread is exiting? Use a system tool/perfmon to see if the thread count is getting large. It could be that someone/something is doing a ThreadAbort on your thread...resulting in a .NET call being rudely interrupted...and may be corrupting some state. Wrap the code in your thread in a  try / catch (ThreadAbortException) and put a breadpoint in the catch / or log it.

Comment: I have the same error with .Net 4.5 and my thread has two catchs: ThreadAbortException and Exception, but my application (windows service)is finished. Have you resolved the problem?